# debug a process with gdb and close the terminal

Tags: linux, debugging, ssh, gdb, setsid

I have a bug in my application which runs on a remote server. After a few hours of execution, the application gets a SIGSEGV and terminates.

I want to debug my remote application with gdb through ssh so when the program gets SIGSEGV gdb will halt and will allow me to see what happened, but I can't leave the ssh session to the server connected. I'm trying to run:

```
setsid gdb my_app
```

but when I close the ssh terminal, gdb and my app terminate immediately.

My questions:

- How can I leave gdb running when closing the terminal
- How can re-connect to it later?

`strace` on gdb on the moment of closing the terminal shows:

```
read(0, 0x7fff0532895f, 1)              = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7fff05328930) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x5b3550, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x5b3710, [TERM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x5b33d0, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x5b33f0, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [TSTP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86ac0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x4efb70, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x7fa0fce86160, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x5b3410, [TSTP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fae70da0}, {SIG_DFL, [TSTP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7fff053288e0) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
write(1, "quit\n", 5)                   = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x5b3550, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fae70da0}, {0x5b3550, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa0fbaa0c90}, {0x5b3550, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fa0fae70da0}, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like 'screen', it will continue to run if you detach from it (CTRL-a d), then you can reconnect later with 'screen -r'.

Or you can reattach gdb with the progam name and the PID, e.g. 'gdb my_app 1234', where the number 1234 has to be replaced by the correct PID.

Comment: Screen is a good suggestion (or tmux), but reattaching with gdb won't work if the program has already terminated with SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the core dump:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Then execute your program (causing seg fault) and you should see "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", when the process crash the system will save a dump, you will be able to analyze it when you want, even though you lost connection.

Then launch `gdb -c core`

Comment: To get to this point, you will need to use nohup or something similar to allow your application to continue running after you disconnect.  If your application writes to the terminal, you will need to redirect its output to a file instead.